# Is there a way to check the sources of users who are joining my Telegram channel?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, channel, utm

I post links to various platforms like YouTube, blogs, and other websites. I'm looking for a way to determine which source or platform a user came from when they join my channel.
Can you assist me in finding a solution for this? Thank you.

There is an option to use intermediate links, but how to connect the subscription with the data from the link?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.